# XMLHttpRequest cannot connect to Google App Enging

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, xmlhttprequest

Client: javascript on Chrome browser
Server: Google App Enging, java servlet
I am trying to get token from server side, here is my js code:

```
var httpRequest;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  // Mozilla, Safari, Chrome,...
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
  // ...
}
if (!httpRequest) {
  alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
  return false;
}
httpRequest.open('POST', 'http://myapp.appspot.com/gettoken?userid=ethan', true);
```

and my servlet server code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
String userId = request.getParameter("userid");
if (userId != null && !"".equals(userId)) {
  String token = createChannel(userId);
  writeIntoChannel(response,token);
}
}
```

basically identical to GAE's CodeLabEx4, just I am moving it's js code to client side. It's original code is

```
httpRequest.open('POST', '/gettoken?userid=ethan', true);
```

That works, but how come after I add the complete url it doesn't work?
status = 0, not 200

```
httpRequest.open('POST', 'http://myapp.appspot.com/gettoken?userid=ethan', true);
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

After some research, I have updated to use ajax() to do the query:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://myapp.appspot.com/gettoken?userid=xxx',
                            type : "POST",
                            data:null,
                            success : function(data) {                                  
                                alert('ok!');
                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                alert(data.statusText);
                            },
                            complete : function() { 
                                //alert("always"); 
                            },

                        });
```

But the returned data.statusText is 'error'.

Comment: Is the page that the js is running on also hosted at `myapp.appspot.com`, or somewhere else like localhost?

Comment: the js client page is local (not hosted at myapp.appspot.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your page is hosted at `localhost`, then your browser is not going to send a valid request to the app engine due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). It is likely sending an `OPT` request, or some other nonsense that will not yield you a real response.

Another clue that SOP is the issue is that the response code is `0`. (See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). `0` is not a real HTTP response code.

Host this page on the app engine or disable SOP in your browser.

Comment: If I deploy the html5/js app to iOS/Android, is it still localhost? Sorry I'm new to web coding :(

Comment: It looks like XMLHttpRequest is not suitable for mobile app purpose. I see there are 5 ways in a book:
1. XMLHttpRequest 2. Dynamic script tag insertion 3. iframes 4. Comet 5. Multipart XHR, which one is suitable? Thanks!